# How to make my wordpress mobile navigation multi-level

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

so, I am building a wordpress theme and create my mobile navigation. After several tries, I finally got a solution I am happy with, but I have one big problem: I can only open 1 level of submenus, if there is a submenu in a submenu, the links are hidde, but I can't figure out how to make them show onclick, as the first level..

This is the js I am using to open the first level:

```
$('ul.nav-mobile > li > a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next();

    $('ul.nav-mobile li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');   

    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('ul.nav-mobile ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;    
    }
});
```

You can see it live on http://wbs.webdesign3r.de (mobile view)

Is there any solution, that lets me add as many sub levels as I want? Or otherwise, what do I need to add to my js for each level?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hallo, try this `$('ul.nav-mobile li > a')` instead of this one `$('ul.nav-mobile > li > a')`

Comment: words 50%.. if I change that and open the menu, then click on the 2nd level submenu, the first level closes, and if i open it again, the 2nd is open..

Comment: Check the answer and please let me know this solution solved your problem or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't include any `html` codes in your Q its a little hard to find ***final*** solution but i think this is the solution.

**js**:

```
$('ul.nav-mobile li > a').click(function() {
    var checkElement = $(this).next(),
        $parent      = $(this).parent('li');

    $parent.addClass('active');   

    if(checkElement.is('ul') && checkElement.is(':visible')) {
        $parent.removeClass('active');
        checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }

    if(checkElement.is('ul') && !checkElement.is(':visible')) {
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }

    if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

This approach bring you another issue, If you close your entire mobile menu and open again, you will see all open sub menus are still open. You can fix that issue by this line of code:

```
$('#nav-icon0').on('click', function(){
    // you can add a if condition here to check this element
    // has '.open' class or not and turn it to just work on close not on open
    $('ul.nav-mobile li.active').removeClass('active');
    $('ul.nav-mobile ul:visible').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. It's the default wordpress menu layout so I thought that info and a link to the page would be enough, sorry. But yeah, this is exactly what I needed!